# Unable to apply case statement in join condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables TableA and TableB. For one of the record in TableB(id =1), I want to perform join on condition1(a.value = b.value) and for other records I want to join on condition2((a.value - b.value)/ a.val < 1).

But, I am getting syntax error at `end`. How to apply case condition in this scenario?

```
Select * from TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b 
on a.id = b.id 
and (
case when b.id = 1 then a.value = b.value 
else (a.value - b.value)/ a.val < 1 end
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use boolean logic:

```
select *
from TableA a left join
     TableB b 
     on a.id = b.id and
        (b.id = 1 and a.value = b.value or
         b.id <> 1 and (a.value - b.value)/ a.val < 1
        )
```